# data-accordion removed in Visual Editor

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, html-editor

Using Foundation 5's accordion, and the data-accordion html data attribute in:

```
<dl class="accordion" data-accordion>
```

gets removed when a user only edits a page with the Visual Editor.

Does anyone know of a way to keep this from happening?

I noticed this [link](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/register-additional-html-attributes-for-tinymce-and-wp-kses/) that allows you to Register Additional HTML Attributes for TinyMCE and WP KSES, though I'm not sure where I'd place `data-accordion` in that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of How to Update kses and TinyMCE to allow select data-* attributes in WordPress. [Reference](https://gist.github.com/mjangda/5826826)

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'x_kses_allow_data_attributes_on_links' );
function x_kses_allow_data_attributes_on_links() {
  global $allowedposttags;

    $tags = array( 'a' );
    $new_attributes = array(
        'data-foo' => array(),
        'data-bar' => array(),
    );

    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        if ( isset( $allowedposttags[ $tag ] ) && is_array( $allowedposttags[ $tag ] ) )
            $allowedposttags[ $tag ] = array_merge( $allowedposttags[ $tag ], $new_attributes );
    }
}

add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'x_tinymce_allow_data_attributes_on_links' );
function x_tinymce_allow_data_attributes_on_links( $options ) { 
    if ( ! isset( $options['extended_valid_elements'] ) ) 
        $options['extended_valid_elements'] = ''; 

    $options['extended_valid_elements'] .= ',a[data-foo|data-bar|class|id|style|href]';

    return $options; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Though, because Foundation uses data-attributes on <dl> and not <a>, should line 7 become `$tags = array( 'dl' );` and line 24 changed to: `',dl[data-accordion|data-tab|class|id|style|href]';` ?