# How to retain HTML5 Attributes on Markup

Tags: admin, editor, customization, html5

I have a page with certain html markup and element attributes as shown in the snippit below:

`<ul class="accordion" data-accordion="">`

When I edit the page as a user with the WP Administrator Role the `<ul>` remains intact upon page update. Perfect.

Yet when a user with WP Editor Role edits the page, the ul tag saves as follows:

`<ul class="accordion">`

Notice the data-accordion attribute is removed.

How can I get WordPress to retain markup tag attributes for users with the Editor role?

Comment: I think this has been answered here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188484/data-accordion-removed-in-visual-editor

Comment: Thanks @EddTwilbeck, but that answer did not solve the specific problem I am encountering. My issue pertains to **Editor** role users not being able to retain certain html5 markup attributes while **Administrator** user can.

Comment: Well it mentions [KSES](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses), which is the reason: it's HTML filtering that's applied to non-administrator users. You'll need to register data-accordion as an allowed attribute. And FWIW you've posted this as an answer when it should have been a comment on your question in reply to Edd's comment: since you haven't registered an account you'd need to come back here on the same browser (i.e. with the same login cookie) and you'd have permission to comment.

Comment: Please _stop_ using answers for comments, really. That doesn't work and gets deleted. If you use same account as you started question with you can always comment in that thread. If you created multiple accounts by mistake you can request to [get them merged](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to add `unfiltered_html` capability to `Editor` role.

Add the following code into your current theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_change_capability() {
    $role = get_role( 'editor' );
    if ( ! $role->has_cap( 'unfiltered_html' ) )
        $role->add_cap( 'unfiltered_html' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_change_capability', 10 );
```

Login as the user with `Editor` role. Test it by editing any post / page. HTML markup will be preserved. Remove the code above from `functions.php`.

If you decide to remove `unfiltered_html` capability from `Editor` role, repeat steps described above, using this code:

```
function wpse_change_capability() {
    $role = get_role( 'editor' );
    if ( $role->has_cap( 'unfiltered_html' ) )
        $role->remove_cap( 'unfiltered_html' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_change_capability', 10 );
```