# How to register data-accordion as an allowed attribute

Tags: admin, editor, customization, html5

Continuing my now protected question from earlier at [How to retain HTML5 Attributes on Markup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232993/how-to-retain-html5-attributes-on-markup/233165#233165):

How do you "register data-accordion as an allowed attribute" @Rup ?

I looked at the Codex and it is not crystal clear. I also did more Googl'ing and found the same answer at http://wordpress.troplet.com/question/data-accordion-removed-in-visual-editor-188484.html but it simply does not work.

Comment: Do you have a code sample you can provide of your non-working code?

Comment: Please stop creating new accounts over and over. [Merge them all](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) instead.