# Possible to add a meta field for css attribute to the editor Advanced panel?

Tags: custom-field, block-editor

I'm working on a child theme based on Foundation. While I can keep editing custom HTML for things like Foundation's built-in accordions, it would be nice if the block editor "Advanced" panel had one little extra field for attributes below the ones for HTML anchor and Additional CSS class(es).

Can this be done in a way similar to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188486/143329) (relevant to the classic editor)?

[image: additional field in editor panel]